# React-Native : Passing variable onClick to handler in different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a new React-Native programmer . I am trying to create a login page but I am not sure how to pass some parameters to a handler function that is located in different files.

I am trying to pass the variable email and password in SignIn.js to onVerify in Auth.js during onClick() button

SignIn.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { Card, Button, FormLabel, FormInput } from "react-native-elements";
import { onVerify } from "../auth";
import { onSignIn } from "../auth";


export default class SignIn extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      const {navigation} = this.props.navigation;
      this.state ={
          email : "huzaifah1011@gmail.com",
          password : "12345",
          name : "",
          logged : false
      }
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
        <Card>
          <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
          <FormInput placeholder="Email address..." />
          <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
          <FormInput secureTextEntry placeholder="Password..." />

          <Button
            buttonStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
            backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
            title="SIGN IN"
            onPress={() => {onVerify(this.state.email,this.state.password);}}
            // {()=> this.onVerify()}

          />
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and for the onClick function which is the onVerify is located in auth.js

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

export const USER_KEY = "auth-demo-key";

export const onSignIn = () => AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, "true");

export const onSignOut = () => AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);

export const onVerify = (email,password) => {
          fetch('xxx',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: 'email=' + this.email + '&password=' + this.password
            })

            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                if(responseJson.status == '200') {
                    onSignIn();
                    () => navigation.navigate("SignedIn")
                }
                console.log(responseJson)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });}
```

Comment: try changing `this.email` and `this.password` to just `email` and `password`. Also a side note, you can do `import { onVerify, onSignIn } from "../auth";` just in a single line.

Comment: Also you need to pass `navigation` prop to the `onVerify` function too.

Comment: @bennygenel why u need navigation.There is an API call based on which navigation done

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much ! @bennygenel

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN because there is no reference to the `navigation` inside the `onVerfy` function. Also that line with navigation seems odd to me. There is a syntax issue too I think

Comment: @bennygenel urm , is it possible to pass the responseJson from onVerify() back to SignIn.js ?

Comment: Because fetch is an async function you can't directly return the value. You return the promise and use it like that. For more info you can search for "returning value from promise"

Answer (score 0):

Add one local function in `SignIn Component`  and from that function call `onVerify` of `auth`.

```
export default class SignIn extends React.Component{

        //add local function
        onVerify = ()=>{
            onVerify(this.state.email,this.state.password);
        }


      render(){
        return(
          <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
            <Card>
              //....
              <Button
                buttonStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
                backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
                title="SIGN IN"
                onPress={() => this.onVerify()} //call the local function

              />
            </Card>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: This seems unnecessary to me. Can you please give more context on why?

Comment: @bennygenel `onVerify` is already imported there.Only need to call it.No need of redirection

Comment: I know it is imported and OP is already running the function onPress. Why should OP add a second function that runs the function?